# Formatting space/tab delineated tables in Sublime Text 2

Tags: optimization, formatting, sublimetext2

I have some code in my routes.rb file like:

```
match 'subscribe' => 'home#subscribe', :as => :subscribe, :method=>:post
match 'identify'=>"home#identify", :as=> :identify
match 'about' => 'home#about_us', :as => :about
match 'how-it-works' => 'home#how_it_works', :as => :how
match 'faq' => 'home#faq', :as => :faq
match 'privacy' => 'home#privacy', :as => :privacy
```

Is there a way to quickly/easily format this in Sublime Text so it's more like:

```
match 'faq'             => 'home#faq',            :as => :faq
match 'privacy'         => 'home#privacy',        :as => :privacy
```

..etc

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [Alignment](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) plugin does. However, I don't know if it handles multiple "alignment" items per line. You may need to write your own macro/plugin to do it, or search around a bit more. You may also want to ask on Sublime Text forums, as they might know about a plugin that does what you want already (though I can't guarantee it :))

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know such a thing existed.

Answer (score 0):

The [AlignTab](https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab) plugin fit better for your purpose.  Is based on the VIM plugin called tabular.

Type **Align Tabular** in command palette, and enter the regex. In the case of your code, a simple regex would be:

> =>|:as

Comment: Knew there had to be a plugin that did it that I didn't know about :)